# How can I convert an image into Base64 string from an image source?

Tags: javascript, html, base64

I have found some answers related to the topic from [How can I convert an image into Base64 string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript/20285053#20285053). I realized they don't have an image on the div tag. Is it possible if I would have the image source?

Answer added for people who want to reference

```js
function encodeImageFileAsURL() {

  var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
  if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
    var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
      var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

      var newImage = document.createElement('img');
      newImage.src = srcData;

        document.getElementById("output").src = newImage.src;
  alert("Converted Base64 version is " + document.getElementById("output").src);
  console.log("Converted Base64 version is " + document.getElementById("output").src);
    }
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL();" />
<img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/placeholder-avatar.jpg" id="output" width="100" height="100" style="border-radius: 50%;" />
```

I would like to use the image source to load the image and find out the base 64. Is it possible?
Besides using div to create 1 image out where it can't be customized.

Comment: Do you mean you have this structure: `<div><img src="someUrl"></div>` and you want to convert that image ? Then do `const url = document.querySelector('img').getAttribute('src');` and use that URL in one of the solutions provided in your link.

Comment: yeap :) i wan to use the image and as well display the base 64 string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do this https://jsfiddle.net/samet19/yv9a4op8/

```
function encodeImageFileAsURL() {
  var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
  if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
    var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
      var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64
      var newImage = document.createElement('img');
      newImage.src = srcData;
      document.getElementById("output").src = newImage.src;
    }
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes i wan do that as well display a base 64 string data as well